# What is the python version required for creating apk files using buildozer

Tags: python, buildozer

I am trying to create apk file using buildozer. It fails with an error related to the Python version

Command:

```
buildozer android debug
```

Failure:

> Command Failed: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colo0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum; python version<"3.4"' 'sh>1.10; sys platfot:'

Comment: show full error message.

Comment: Command Failed: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user 'apdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"'' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"'

#
#Buildozer failed to execute the last command
#If the error isnot obvious ,please raise the log_level to 2

Comment: Run that command manually and you will see what was the exact problem. Or rise log_level to 2.

Comment: I ran the command it says to upgrade the python version.I tried using pip install but could'nt install python 3 in /usr/bin path .can you help regarding this please

Answer (score 2):

Here it says on their [Github](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) repository:

> For Android, buildozer will automatically download and prepare the build dependencies. For more information, see Android-SDK-NDK-Information. We recommend targeting Python 3 on Android, but you can target both Python 3 and Python 2 regardless of which version you use with buildozer on the desktop.

- So it's recommended to use python 3.
  but again consider reading their documentation [here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- As for your question, there's also a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users) discussion about bugs and problems.
- Links taken from [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/) repository.

Comment: Iam unable to install python3 in /usr/bin of my virtual box ubuntu machine..Can you suggest me a way so that I can customize my buildozer to work for python 2.7

Comment: Also if possible suggest how to install python3 in /usr/bin path.I tried it many times but couldnt do it

Comment: @GopalaRaok you can check out these helpful tutorials over here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04         also check this one: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/